# Jackrabbit repository incremental backup

Tags: backup, jackrabbit, jcr

I'm using Jackrabbit v2.2.x. I want to know if is there a way to take incremental backup of a jackrabbit repository? I mean, just the delta (difference) based on date or something else. Actually the problem is that the repository size is in TeraBytes and every time we have to take production data it takes a lot of time to copy full repository.

Answer (score 1):

If the storage backend support incremental backups, an incremental [low level backup](http://wiki.apache.org/jackrabbit/BackupAndMigration#Low_Level_Backup) might be the easiest solution.

If not, possibly you could use the [EventJournal](http://www.day.com/maven/jsr170/javadocs/jcr-2.0/javax/jcr/observation/EventJournal.html) to iterate over the changes since the last backup, and just backup those changes. Most likely this will require more work however.

Another solution is to do an incremental backup of the data store (if this is what uses most of the disk space), and do a full backup of the node data (persistence managers).